# qt render chart does not update title/legend

Tags: c++, qt, rendering, qtcharts

I'm trying to render a QChartView into a .png image using the following simplyfied code:

```
QChartView *chartView = /* pointer to chart view */;
const auto dpr = chartView->devicePixelRatioF();
chartView->setMinimumSize(500, 500);
chartView->setMaximumSize(500, 500);
QImage image(500, 500, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
image.setDevicePixelRatio(dpr);
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
chartView->render(&painter);
image.save('image.png');
```

It works fine and it saves an image as intended. 
However, if I try to change the title before rendering the title is not shown:

```
QChartView *chartView = /* pointer to chart view */;
const auto dpr = chartView->devicePixelRatioF();
chartView->setMinimumSize(500, 500);
chartView->setMaximumSize(500, 500);
chartView->chart()->setTitle("my title"); // <--- HERE
QImage image(500, 500, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
image.setDevicePixelRatio(dpr);
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
chartView->render(&painter);
image.save('image.png');
```

However, if I create a button which displays a title, and a button which should save the image and I first click the button to show the title and then the button to save the image it works. (Meaning, if I separate the two steps, so that in between the chart is displayed in the GUI it works)

The same is true when I try to show a legend.

**Update: I have added a complete minimal example to reproduce the problem:**

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
    series->setName("label");

    series->append(0, 6);
    series->append(2, 4);
    series->append(3, 8);
    series->append(7, 4);
    series->append(10, 5);
    *series << QPointF(11, 1) << QPointF(13, 3) << QPointF(17, 6) << QPointF(18, 3) << QPointF(20, 2);

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    chart->setTitle("");
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chartView->grab().toImage().save("noLabels.png");

    chart->setTitle("title");
    chart->legend()->show();
    chartView->grab().toImage().save("withLabels.png");

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(400, 300);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

both created images `noLabels.png` and `withLabels.png` do not show a title or a legend.

Comment: Try `chartView->grab().toImage().save("image.png");` instead of using `QPainter`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this hint. Your code is a lot simpler and more straight forward as mine. Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the events are queued and processed later when you set title or show legend. You can force them to take place by resizing the chart view after setting title and showing legend:

```
chart->setTitle("title");
chart->legend()->show();
chartView->resize(QSize(500,500));
chartView->grab().toImage().save("withLabels.png");
```

Comment: Thanks, resize did the trick. I'll accept your answer in a minute. One last thing: I am creating these images in a loop. In order to use your solution, I have to resize the chartView twice so that it really changes the size at every iteration. I'm using `resize(499,499)` followed by `resize(500,500)` which works but is a bit confusing for other people to understand. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @user7431005 One other solution is to call `qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);` instead of resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use `repaint()` before setting the title?

Comment: repaint did not help